# Integration testing between web application and WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using `WebApplicationFactory<TStartup>` for integration testing  of a .NET Core 3.0 web application.
It works when it  need to test just one web application.

But what if  web application need to send request to WebAPI application. I need somehow to instantiate both `WebApplicationFactory<Web.Startup>` and `WebApplicationFactory<Api.Startup>`.

I tried different alternatives with no luck. 
Can anybody with experience of similar task point a right way to me.

P.S. Inside web application there is injected internal `HttpClient` that used internally in Controllers to send requests to API:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient<IInternalApiClient, InternalApiClient>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't. What you're talking about would be a "systems test", i.e. testing the whole system. Integration testing is about making sure the sub-components of a single application function together. As such, you'd mock the the service class that calls out to your API: `InternalApiClient`. In your test server's web host setup, you'd create a mock of `IInternalApiClient` and stub the appropriate methods to return dummy data instead of actually calling out to the API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Additional question please: how would you recommend to write Selenium tests if web app depends on API?

Comment: Oh, okey, maybe also with mocking of api responses

Comment: Selenium is for UI testing, so you'd want a specific environment for that, since you need the full system in place. The data could dummy test data, but you'd still want a real deployment.